# Swiftでコード側からsiriを立ち上げる事はできますか？

Tags: swift, ios, xcode

Swiftでコード側からsiriを立ち上げる事はできますか？

Comment: SiriKitの話でしょうか？それとも全然別の話ですか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。すでにアプリを使用している中での文字の入力時にキーボードのSiriボタンを押して音声入力する状態を、コード側から、こちらが指定したタイミングでつくりたいと思っています。SiriKitというのは、今知りました。もし、SiriKitで可能であればそれでも大丈夫です。SiriKitでアプリを起動して、そのまま入力というのができればそちらの方がもっと便利だと思います。

Answer (score 1):

Siriを起動するだけなら本家SOに既に下記の質問がありました。

[APIを使用してアプリのプログラムからSiriを呼び出せる？](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649602/)

```
#import "GSEvent.h"

- (void)launchSiri {
   [self simulateTouchEvent: kGSEventMenuButtonDown];

   double delayInSeconds = 1.0;
   dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
   dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
      [self simulateTouchEvent: kGSEventMenuButtonUp];
   });
}

- (void)simulateTouchEvent: (GSEventType)type
{
   struct GSEventRecord record;
   memset(&record, 0, sizeof(record));
   record.type = type;
   record.timestamp = GSCurrentEventTimestamp();
   GSSendSystemEvent(&record);  
}
```

---

残念ながら私もSiriKitを勉強中なので仰ることを実現できるか分かっておりません。
(実現は出来ておりませんが、[Siriからアプリの機能を呼び出すことが可能](http://qiita.com/yokomotod/items/cdc21d0dc185e77a7139)なようです)
[Apple SiriKit](https://developer.apple.com/sirikit/)ですが、サポートがiOS10からのようですので、
過去にサポートしていたOSも……となると難しいかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます！読んでみます。